# Why do I keep getting "Killed: 9" when I run this very basic SQLite3 based C file?

Tags: c, gcc, sqlite

I have this super basic C file:

```
#include <sqlite3.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    printf("%s\n", sqlite3_libversion()); 

    return 0;
}
```

And in the same directory I have `sqlite3.h`, `sqlite3.c` and `sqlite3ext.h` downloaded from [the downloads page on sqlite.org](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html).

I then run `gcc -c main.c`. Then `chmod +x main.o`. Then `./main.o`. And every time I get:

```
Killed: 9
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot execute a relocatable object file directly like that.  Try this:

```
gcc main.c -o main -lsqlite3
```

This works on Ubuntu with `libsqlite3-dev` package installed.  Running main results in:

```
 3.8.2
```

The `-o` flag specifies the name of the executable file.  If you ommit `-o main`, you'll get a file called `a.out` with gcc on most platforms (maybe a.exe on windows+cygwin?). Either way, this file will already be executable, so you can skip the `chmod +x`.

The `-lsqlite3` flag tells the compiler to link in the sqlite3 library too.

If you've built sqlite3 from scratch, you may also need `-I` and `-L` flags to tell the compiler where to look for libraries and headers.

In your command, the "-c" flag skips the linking stage and produces a relocatable object, where otherwise, gcc will produce an executable file.

You can use `readelf -h main.o` using output of your original command and `readelf -h main` using output of my suggested command, or alternatively just `file main.o` and `file main` to see differences in file types.

Comment: Your actual compiled file may be a.out or similar, by default, if you do not specify the name as shown in this answer.

Comment: And the OP doesn't need to `chmod` the resulting file, it's just that the resulting file in this case is not an executable, i'ts a object file.

Comment: @DougSmith - you're missing a shared library.  You'll need a `-l` flag to specify the library.  Maybe `-lsqlite3`?

Comment: @EricJ. & iharob - Incorporated your feedback into answer.  Thanks.